# java - get key from byte array

Tags: java, public-key, cryptoapi

I have a java program that encrypts file content with a random-generated key.
That key is encrpyted with RSA and saved into a text file.

Now, I have a java program that given the file and the keystore where the RSA key is stored, needs to first decrypt the encryped key and then with the key to decrypt the file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// Fetch the other public key and decrypt the file encryption key
java.security.cert.Certificate cert2 = keystore.getCertificate("keyForSeckeyDecrypt");
Key secKeyPublicKey = cert2.getPublicKey();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(secKeyPublicKey.getAlgorithm());
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKeyPublicKey);
keyFileFis = new FileInputStream(keyFile);
byte[] encryptedKey = new byte[128];
keyFileFis.read(encryptedKey);
byte[] realFileKey = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKey, 0, encryptedKey.length);
Key realKey = //  THE PROBLEM!!!;
keyFileFis.close();
```

In short, I get the encrypted key from the key text file and decrypt it, now I have the decrypted key as a byte array, how would I make it a Key variable again?

I've generated the key this way:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
Key secKey = keyGen.generateKey();
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
```

And encrypted it this way:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
Cipher keyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
keyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] encryptedKey = keyCipher.doFinal(secKey.getEncoded());
FileOutputStream keyStream = new FileOutputStream("key.txt");
keyStream.write(encryptedKey);
keyStream.close();
```

Comment: Can you share how you generate key that is stored in file? Algorithm? Length?

Comment: Just to be sure! You encrypt your `aes` key with "newly generated" `RSA` private key and save it to the file. But you expect to decrypt it with public key from your keystore! It does not make sense to me. You should use private key from keystore to get it work.

Comment: @Akdeniz, the key I except the decrypt from the keystore is the RSA public key, so I can have the RSA private key, so I can decrypt my AES key. Encrypting the AES key with RSA is one of the exercise's requirements, if you have better offer to design it, I'd love to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but from clicking through the API [SecretKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html) could be what you are looking for.

```
SecretKeySpec(byte[] key, String algorithm)
```

> It can be used to construct a SecretKey from a byte array, without having to go through a (provider-based) SecretKeyFactory.
>
> This class is only useful for raw secret keys that can be represented as a byte array and have no key parameters associated with them, e.g., DES or Triple DES keys.

Comment: I've tried that already, but when I do it, and try to initialize a Cipher with this SecretKeySpec,I get an exception "No installed provider supports this key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec"

Comment: @MichBoy That is the right way to recreate the key. The problem is probably that your key is the wrong size. An AES key would be 16, 24, or 32 bytes, not 128. To use a key longer than 128 bytes, you need the unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, this should work..

```
Key privateKey = keyStore.getKey("youralias", "password".toCharArray());
PublicKey publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate("youralias").getPublicKey();

KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
Key secKey = keyGen.generateKey();

Cipher keyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
keyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] encryptedKey = keyCipher.doFinal(secKey.getEncoded());

// Write & Read to/from file!

Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] decryptedKey = decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedKey);

boolean equals = Arrays.equals(secKey.getEncoded(), new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKey, "AES").getEncoded());
System.out.println(equals?"Successfull!":"Failed!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the great effort, some points: a) The encryption and decryption are in two different classes (i.e. different programs) so secKey is in the encryption program but no in the decryption one. b) I still don't have my problem solved, because I need a key Variable for the decryption of the original file.

Comment: By the way, for some reason, when trying to do the decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedKey) part, I get "Data mush start with a zero" exception, why?

Comment: Be sure that you can read exactly what you write to that file. By the way, this code is just a proof of concept that you can recreate your `AES` key with `SecretKeySpec`. If you have a problem with your context, please ask another question, directing to your problem clearly.